# Oracle SQL - look up 2 columns from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have 2 tables,

Reg_table

```
student_ID   Course_ID   **Register**_status
    1           co_01       enrolled
    2           co_03       pending
    3           co_05       cancelled
    4           co_06       enrolled
```

Compl_table

```
student_ID   Course_ID   **Completion**_status
    1           co_01       Attended
    1           co_03       
    3           co_05       
    4           co_06       Attended
    4           co_05       
    6           co_05
```

I would like to add a new status to Reg_table as 'Final_status', looking up from 'Compl_table', based on the combination of 'Student_ID' and 'Course_ID' of both tables. i.e. 
*If a student 'enrolled' on co_01 and then 'Attended' co_01, the final status should say 'Attended; 
*If the 'completion_status' is blank or the combo of 'Student_ID' and 'Course_ID' doesn't exist in 'Compl_table', the final status should be the same as 'Register_status' i.e. 'enrolled', 'pending' or 'cancelled'.

Therefore, the results table should look like:

`student_ID   Course_ID   **Final**_status

    1           co_01       Attended
    2           co_03       pending
    3           co_05       cancelled
    4           co_06       Attended`

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Added code (sorry bit more complicated than the example), where I got to so far

```
with reg_table as 

(select 
b.schd_id
,b.DMN_ID
,b.ACT_CPNT_ID
,b.CPNT_TYP_ID
,b.SCHD_DESC
,b.FACILITY_ID
,a.STUD_ID
,a.ENRL_STAT_ID
,a.ENRL_DTE
,c.CMPL_STAT_ID 
from 
 PA_ENROLL_SEAT a
,PA_SCHED b
,pa_cpnt_evthst c 
where
    a.schd_id = b.schd_id
    and
    b.ACT_CPNT_ID = c.CPNT_ID(+)
    and
    a.STUD_ID = c.STUD_ID(+) 
)
update reg_table r
    set CMPL_STAT_ID = (select CMPL_STAT_ID from pa_cpnt_evthst c where 
         c.stud_id = a.stud_id and c.CPNT_ID = b.ACT_CPNT_ID)

where exists (select 1
                  from pa_cpnt_evthst c
                  where c.stud_id = a.stud_id and
                        c.CPNT_ID = b.ACT_CPNT_ID and
                        c.CMPL_STAT_ID is not null
                 )
```

Comment: And what happened go `co_03` for student `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
Select r.student_ID, r.Course_ID, nvl(c.Completion_status, r.Register_status) as Final_status
From Reg_table R
  left outer join Compl_table C on c.student_ID = r.student_ID and c.Course_ID = r.Course_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike. This has worked beautifully! :D

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
update reg_table r
    set register_status = (select c.completion_status
                           from compl_table c
                           where c.student_id = r.student_id and
                                 c.course_id = r.course_id
                          )
    where exists (select 1
                  from compl_table c
                  where c.student_id = r.student_id and
                        c.course_id = r.course_id and
                        c.completion_status is not null
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I tried to incorporate your solution into my code, but didn't seem to work, probably because of my own fault. Would you be kind enough to tell me let me know where I'm going wrong please? I've pasted my code above.

Comment: @JakeB . .  . In Oracle regular expressions are part of the `select` statement, but not `update` (or `delete`).  In addition, updating such a complex query is unlikely to work.  I would suggest that you ask another question.  When you do, write the query using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.